# UIPopover release iOS

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I have `@property(nonatomic,retain) UIPopoverController * popoverController;`

I create my popover in my implementation class.

I use this:

```
- (void)createPopover:(NavigationController *)tempNavigation {

            UIPopoverController *tempPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tempNavigation];
            self.popoverController = tempPopover;
            [self.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
            tempPopover.delegate = self;                

            CGRect selectedRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];             
            [tempPopover presentPopoverFromRect:selectedRect inView:self.tableView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
            [tempPopover release];
}
```

in this method I need to release my popover

i use this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (popoverController) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
        self.popoverController=nil; 
        [popoverController release];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

My question: this right way to release popover in this method. Or I must release popover in dealloc method only?

Comment: You can release a retained/allocated object anywhere, as long as you don't try to access or release it again. So this is fine

Comment: First you are setting the property to Nil then you Release the instance variable - both will effectively release the popover, hence you may remove One or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.popoverController=nil;
```

calls the setter. Given your property is declared as retain this will release the previous value and retain the new one (in this case it retains nil which does nothing).

```
[popoverController release];
```

calls release on popoverController which is now nil which does nothing. However you should not do it, if it had not been nil it would be over released (as release would be called on it also the next time you set the popoverController property).

You also have a problem when you set the property

```
UIPopoverController *tempPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tempNavigation];
self.popoverController = tempPopover;
```

the setter retains the value so you should autorelease it

```
self.popoverController = [tempPopover autorelease];
```

And you should use ARC :)